# Access 2013 retrieving data from textboxes on a form and inserting them into a new table based on the click on a command button

Tags: ms-access, textbox, vba, command

Im looking for some help in creating a form than when data is entered into text boxes by the user and then submitted by the click of a command button populates a table as a new record.

My table im looking to put the data in is UserData and the textboxes I plan on using are txtManHours2 , txtAMTs2, txtDuration2, and txtToolsRequired2. I do not have these textboxes bound they are all unbounded. Should I bound them to the table?

Thank You!

Comment: If you bind a table to the form and fields to the controls, MS Access will automatically save the data, stopping it saving is more difficult.

Comment: Well I have half of my form boud to a table that pulls historical data and the other half is when the user enters if they agree with the historical data and the comman button transfers their data to a different table

Comment: Then just move to a new record and write the data from form 1 to form 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you are going for, but if I understand correctly you want to verify the information is correct and make an entry in another table with any changes.

I think the best way would be to create your table UserData with columns:
RelatedID (Number), ManHours2 , AMTs2, Duration2, ToolsRequired2

Then create a query that contains the original fields ie (ManHours AMTs Duration adn ToolsRequired) and the fields from the new table.

You will then add a relationship between the two tables by connecting the Primary Key (ID) from the original table and drag it to the (RelatedID) from the new table

It will be a LEFT join ie ALL of the original table and only the UserData table entires that match. *VERY IMPORTANT

Then make a form based on the query and delete the RelatedID from the FORM only. Now you will have a form that will automatically create a new record and link it to the original. Just make sure to disable to fields that are linked to the original table so the values in the original table cannot be changed.

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Thank you,